# Linking two QMainWindow pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

guys am trying to write a program that takes details from one window and imports them onto a profile of another window.. i want it be on the same app... all i see is qdialog class and I dont wanna use it

am taking data from the first window to import it to the second window

here's my code of the first

```
def loader(self):       
    widget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(widget)
    #layouts
    self.layout = QFormLayout()
    self.descriLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.buttonLayout = QHBoxLayout()

    #QFormLayout dealz
    self.name = QLabel('name')
    items = ['male' , 'female' , 'none']
    self.sexchooser = QComboBox()
    for item in items:
        self.sexchooser.addItem(item)

    self.age = QLabel('age')
    self.optcourse = QLabel('Opted Course')
    self.nameEdit = QLineEdit()
    #self.nameEdit.editingFinished()
    self.nameEdit.setPlaceholderText('enter name here')
    self.coursEdit = QLineEdit()
    self.coursEdit.setPlaceholderText('Mt || Ph || St')
    self.sexLabel = QLabel('sex')
    #age selector
    self.ageSelector = QComboBox()
    for x in range(18 , 40):
        self.ageSelector.addItem(str(x))
    self.descriptor = QPlainTextEdit()

    self.descriptor.setPlaceholderText('describe yourself here')
    self.descriptor.setUndoRedoEnabled(True)
    self.layout.addRow(self.name , self.nameEdit)
    self.layout.addRow(self.optcourse , self.coursEdit)
    self.layout.addRow(QLabel('sex') , self.sexchooser)
    self.layout.addRow(QLabel('Age') , self.ageSelector)

    #buttons dealz
    self.SubmitButton = QPushButton('&Submit')
    self.SubmitButton.clicked.connect(self.detailer)
    self.cancelButton = QPushButton("Can&cel")
    self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
    self.buttonLayout.addWidget(self.SubmitButton)
    self.buttonLayout.addWidget(self.cancelButton)


    self.descriLayout.addLayout(self.layout)
    self.descriLayout.addWidget(self.descriptor)
    self.descriLayout.addLayout(self.buttonLayout)

    self.show()
    widget.setLayout(self.descriLayout)
    self.setMinimumSize(300 , 350)
    self.setMaximumSize(300 , 350)
    self.setWindowTitle('DETAILS')
def detailer(self):
    #the second window called here
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.loader()

    def loader(self):       
        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        #layouts
        self.layout = QFormLayout()
        self.descriLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.buttonLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        #QFormLayout dealz
        self.name = QLabel('name')
        items = ['male' , 'female' , 'none']
        self.sexchooser = QComboBox()
        for item in items:
            self.sexchooser.addItem(item)

        self.age = QLabel('age')
        self.optcourse = QLabel('Opted Course')
        self.nameEdit = QLineEdit()
        #self.nameEdit.editingFinished()
        self.nameEdit.setPlaceholderText('enter name here')
        self.coursEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.coursEdit.setPlaceholderText('Mt || Ph || St')
        self.sexLabel = QLabel('sex')
        #age selector
        self.ageSelector = QComboBox()
        for x in range(18 , 40):
            self.ageSelector.addItem(str(x))
        self.descriptor = QPlainTextEdit()

        self.descriptor.setPlaceholderText('describe yourself here')
        self.descriptor.setUndoRedoEnabled(True)
        self.layout.addRow(self.name , self.nameEdit)
        self.layout.addRow(self.optcourse , self.coursEdit)
        self.layout.addRow(QLabel('sex') , self.sexchooser)
        self.layout.addRow(QLabel('Age') , self.ageSelector)

        #buttons dealz
        self.SubmitButton = QPushButton('&Submit')
        self.SubmitButton.clicked.connect(self.detailer)
        self.cancelButton = QPushButton("Can&cel")
        self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.buttonLayout.addWidget(self.SubmitButton)
        self.buttonLayout.addWidget(self.cancelButton)


        self.descriLayout.addLayout(self.layout)
        self.descriLayout.addWidget(self.descriptor)
        self.descriLayout.addLayout(self.buttonLayout)

        self.show()
        widget.setLayout(self.descriLayout)
        self.setMinimumSize(300 , 350)
        self.setMaximumSize(300 , 350)
        self.setWindowTitle('DETAILS')

    def detailer(self):
        print("#the second window called here")
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Switched to window 2")

        valueText = " {} \n {} \n {} \n {} \n {}"\
                    .format(self.nameEdit.text(), 
                              self.coursEdit.text(),
                              self.sexchooser.currentText(),
                              self.ageSelector.currentText(),
                              self.descriptor.toPlainText())

        self.cams = Window2(valueText, self) 
        self.cams.show()        


class Window2(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, value, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(750, 100, 300, 350)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setWindowTitle('Window2')
        self.setWindowIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_FileDialogInfoView))

        label1 = QLabel(value)
        self.button = QPushButton()
        self.button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.button.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_ArrowLeft))
        self.button.setIconSize(QSize(200, 200))

        layoutV = QVBoxLayout()
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(0,0,255); color: #fff')
        self.pushButton.setText('Click me!')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.goMainWindow)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH.addWidget(label1)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.button)
        layoutV.addLayout(layoutH)
        self.setLayout(layoutV)

    def goMainWindow(self):
        self.parent.show()
        self.close()         


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: @emansa If my answer helped you, do not forget to mark it as useful.